# Suggest a solution for event notification using nServiceBus

Tags: events, nservicebus

Currently we are looking for a solution to have unique profile for our user. We are having a different set of applications and the different profiles like is SAP , in DB and in AD too. We want to make sure If user alters his/her profile from any of application it should have replicate in all the data sources. We are looking for **NServiceBus** as the option for event notification as all subscribed applications will receive notification through bus if there is any change. Can anyone suggest me solution based on the NServiceBus? What pros/cons will be there?

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus would be suitable for addressing this, however it would more likely be through the use of sagas rather than publish/subscribe.